# Null FormData value converted to "null" string in .netcore 2.2 controller

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core

I'm trying to send an Ajax POST using FormData.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('id', 1);
data.append('description', null);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/TestController/UpdateDescription',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: [...]
});
```

In the controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateDescription(int id, string description)
{
    //description = "null", instead of null.
    bool isDescriptionNull = String.IsNullOrEmpty(description); //false!
}
```

I'm using the same code in a different .NET 4.7 project and this does not happens, and I get a *null* value for description.

What's happening here?

Comment: According to the asp mvc core code it might have changed :
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/SimpleTypeModelBinder.cs#L86

Maybe you should consider writing your own model binder if the default one doesn't meet your requirements. Otherwise you shouldn't append null value for description.

Comment: "and I get a null value for description" ← Aren't you passing `null` for `description` though? `data.append('description', null);`

Comment: @Igor OP, means null transforms to "null" as string.

Comment: Try specifying the content type header, example: `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` so the server knows how to parse the data on the request.

Comment: Looks like this this is an expected behaviour: formsData.appends only accepts a string value or a Blob. So it is "correct" that null is converted to "null". Maybe the .NET framework did some magic behind the scenes.

For now, the easiest way is to add a check in javascript for the value, and not sending it at all if null:

`if (title.value) data.append('title', title.value);`

Answer (score 2):

Any value passed into data.append will be converted to a string. The only way to accomplish sending a null value is the send an empty string. i.e. `data.append('description', '');` This will send a null value to the backend without stringifying it.